# Unpacking and dumping executable from DLL

Tags: immunity-debugger, dumping

I'm trying to unpack and dump executable from a DLL packed file, I've loaded the DLL to Immunity Debugger using LOADDLL.exe.

I think I've reached the OEP `0x3DADDD` (the memory location of the unpacked code has been allocated with VirtualAlloc), When I'm trying to dump the unpacked code with OllyDumpEx I get the LOADDLL.exe sections and not the unpacked dump file sections (The dumped file is LOADDLL.exe), How can I dump the unpacked code and fix imports?
[image: OEP + OllyDumpEx]
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using the starting address of the lpbuffer from 
WriteProcessMemory function and than setting OllyDump to that address (3rd option below Module) :
[image]
After that if needed you can fix the IAT table with a tool like:
[Scylla](https://github.com/NtQuery/Scylla)

Comment: Thanks, I was able to find the PE Base, but when i try to Dump I get `Invalid Image Base` error https://s31.postimg.org/gwm54v27v/Screen_Shot_2016_07_20_at_5_57_09_PM.png